# When to use Lists, Sets, Dictionaries, or tuples in python?

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and I'm a bit confused about the use cases of data types in python

Can someone please explain in detail when to use each data type, with an **example** if possible

Thank you.

Comment: You have [tutorials](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) and [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#module-collections) for that.

Comment: Please go through the [Official Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: Are you new to Python or new to programming in general? Anyways, it is not about learning the difference between Python's list, sets, dictionaries. You have to start learning about the data structures first and how each differs from each other. If you already know that an array is consecutively stored data in memory allowing access by index, and that hash tables implement a hasher function which will be used to identify the location of the accessed data, etc., then you would know when to use list and when to use set or dict as you would understand how each data structure works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are used when you have data you want to further modify, alter like sorting and all.

Dictionary is used when you have to sets of data where data of the first set corresponds to data of other set. And the position of the data doesn't matter only the relation of the two sets matters.

A tuple is used when position of the data is very important and you don't want to alter the position throughout.